# Recalibrating speedometer over OBD-II

Tags: obd-ii, speedometer

Is it usually possible to adjust the deliberate lying of the speedometer?

My Renault Twingo reads about 5% too much, but the odometer is spot on, so the computer knows the right speed.

Also, we're getting a Toyota Yaris, which is also reading too much, which will be getting annoying, because it reads the speed signs, so it will alert when driving 5% slower than the speed limit.

If the speedometer lying can't be corrected, can I lie to the computer so it thinks it has smaller wheels, so the speedometer is right, and the odometer id off (getting better resale... he he)

Comment: Welcome to this Stack. I believe it can be done, but you'd have to get your vehicle a new tune in order to do it. You could even possibly do it yourself, but the cost would probably be exorbitant considering you'd have to purchase the software and equipment to be able to do it, plus then learn how to use the software/equipment in the first place. I'm sure you can have this done, but leaving this as a comment because I'm not experienced with Renault's or other European vehicles for that matter.

Comment: I, personally, don't think that the computer system provided by the manufacturer will be able to change those settings - even to find out then either go to a dealer or purchase the manufacturer's computer system - an OBD-II reader from the internet will definitely not have the capability. However, as you may be wanting to do this to cheat the resale value I am not inclined to comment further. Based on your last phrase "so the speedometer is right, and the odometer id off (getting better resale... he he)".

Comment: Actually; I have only once sold a car, the rest have been scrapped.